# Is squaring both sides allowed in implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Suppose I have to find $y’$ in $\sqrt{x+y}=x^3+y^3$. Then instead of differentiating directly, can I first square both sides and then differentiate?

My opinion is that we can’t do it as the original equation is one piece of the equation that we get after squaring. Am I correct on this conclusion? I appreciate if someone can confirm because it is little bit confusing as we can get a similar form for $y’$ for both situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you square both sides, then you get

$$(\sqrt{x+y})^2=(x^3+y^3)^2$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{d(\sqrt{x+y})^2}{dx}=\frac{d(x^3+y^3)^2}{dx}$$

Which by the chain rule can be written as:

$$2\frac{d(\sqrt{x+y})}{dx}=2\frac{d(x^3+y^3)}{dx}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{d(\sqrt{x+y})}{dx}=\frac{d(x^3+y^3)}{dx}.$$

So squaring both sides and then differentiating is fine.

Comment: I think he wants to get rid of the square root in the left-hand side.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am showing it is fine to square both sides to get rid of the square root.

Comment: @smcc
It looks like squaring both sides of an equation does not change the implicit derivative, but what about the inverse problem. Can you take the square root of both sides of an equation, then implicit differentiate. Will you get the same solution as if you had not done so?
For example if you had the equation $(x^2 + 3y^2)^4 = (2x + 3y)^2$ and wanted to find $\rm  \frac{dy}{dx}$, it would make sense to take the square root first before taking implicit derivative.